# Ubuntu 20.04 - Disable laptop built in monitor slows down the system

Tags: multiple-monitors, power-management, laptop, performance, monitor

I am trying to connect my laptop to two external monitors and disable the built in monitor, in order to work only on the two external monitors. However, when I disable the build in monitor, all the system start to slow down.

I've encountered in the past the same issue when I close the lid. I was able to overcome that problem by adding "IgnoreLid=true" into "/etc/UPower/UPower.conf". However now I do not know how to handle this new problem when I disable the built in monitor.

I know it is related to some "Power Saving Mechanism", but I can not figure out how to say him something like "Ignore when the built in monitor is disabled".

Thanks to everyone who can give an hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had the same issue while using DisplayLink on my Dell XPS with Ubuntu 20.04.

[It has been long discussed in the DisplayLink EVDI GitHub repository.](https://github.com/DisplayLink/evdi/issues/181)

It is an issue in the xserver-xorg-core package, and as of now (July 17th 2021) seems to not be fixed in Ubuntu 20.04 as I have my system up to date. You can install anyway the package with the fix as said at: https://www.displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=67148

1. Download the package from: https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/file?d=310
2. Unzip the file and execute `sudo dpkg -i xserver-xorg-core_1.20.8-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb`

I am not sure if a restart was needed, but I did it anyway and it works fine now! :)

If you want to rollback to the default xserver-xorg-core version from the Ubuntu repository you can just execute `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core`

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.10 with the same problem. I get `no such file or directory` when running your command. Is `xserver-xorg-core...` supposed to be inside the package? Because there isn't anything similar to that

Comment: @splaytreez Yes, it used to be inside the zip file

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same problem.

For me, I am using a Dell XPS Laptop and using it with Lenovo docking station (which also uses DisplayLink chipset) however downgrading the xserver didn't help me.

As a workaround, for now, try this command

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --auto
```

`eDP-1` refers to my laptop's internal monitor, you can find out your internal monitor using:

```
xrandr -q
```

It will list all the monitors and display settings possible, look for Screen 0 and use the value mentioned.

While there are many threads referring to this problem, one of them being the Displaylink driver issue (in case you are using DisplayLink Docks).

Hope it helps!

Cheers!

Ranjan Batra

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but, that command will enable the monitor, and the issue here is to disable it, but avoid the slow down.